# Error - Only Assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I have the following error displaying after running my program I am creating in Visual Studios.

Error   1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement   F:\CS4\Form1.cs 103 21  CS4

Below is the set of code that it is saying where this error is occurring...

```
 catch (FormatException err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Pay Rate must be numeric. " + err.Message,
                        "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation;
                    txtPayRate.SelectAll ();
                    txtPayRate.Focus ();
```

The text MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation; is where it highlights when I click on the error message

I am not sure why it keeps saying this. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is missing a closing brace, I assume that was an error in copying it over to SO and not really in your application. I think your error will go away if you make `MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation` the final argument passed to `MessageBox.Show` rather than having it on a line of it's own.

```
 catch (FormatException err)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Pay Rate must be numeric. " + err.Message,
                    "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    txtPayRate.SelectAll();
    txtPayRate.Focus();
  }
```

The error is essentially saying you have a line that isn't valid C#. It lists all of the things you *can* do. `MessageBoxIcon.Exlamation;` as it's own line does nothing. You're just accessing some value but you're not assigning it anywhere or passing it to any method or doing any operation on it which is why the error is produced.

Comment: I just tried the way you explained and it is just giving me now simple errors to correct then once I do it is still giving me the same message

Comment: @LindsayMartino there was a typo in my answer which I just removed. I don't know if that will fix your problem. If it does not you likely have another error elsewhere because that code works.

Comment: Yes I just fixed it and it worked : ) thank you so much for your help